# How to combine multiple dichotomous variable (yes/no) and get multiple response table in R?

Tags: r

In my dataset,and I have several variables like this -

```
Hypertension = 1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1
Diabetes = 1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1
Other NCD = 1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1
```

here, 1 = yes and 0 = No

Now I want to bind all of these "yes" responses from the above variables and create a multiple responses table like this -

[image]

SPSS has a function called "Multiple Response". This image is one of the outputs of this function.
How do I create this table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example with expected output for that example

Comment: Actually, I have no idea what package or function do I need to use to create this multiple responses table as I am a newbie to R.But I made some edits to my question, please see it might give some idea about what I am trying to produce.

Comment: I am guessing that you may need `tables` `tabular` or `ftable`

Comment: I made some edits to my question. please see it might give some idea about what I am trying to produce

Comment: or `xtabs` might be useful

Comment: Shakil, it's a little difficult to help with code when you don't know your intended output given this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  Hypertension = c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1),
  Diabetes =  c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1),
  `Other NCD` = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1),
  check.names = FALSE
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
dat %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(everything(), names_to="k", values_to="v") %>%
  group_by(k) %>%
  summarize(
    n = n(), 
    cases = sum(v), 
    percent = 100 * cases / n()
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(overall = 100 * cases / sum(n))
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   k                n cases percent overall
#   <chr>        <int> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Diabetes         8     5    62.5    20.8
# 2 Hypertension     8     6    75      25  
# 3 Other NCD        8     4    50      16.7
```

Comment: I think to match the OP output, you might want: `mutate(overall = 100 * cases / sum(cases))` in the last line. Upvoting. (Correct me if I'm wrong here...)

Comment: Thanks, probably correct. I'm hoping this (and akrun's answer) are good for steering the OP in the direction of how-to-summarize, so they can adapt it to what more they need. Thanks, Ben!

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, we can do

```
dat1 <- transform(stack(colSums(dat)), n = nrow(dat))
dat1$percent <- 100 *dat1$values/dat1$n
dat1$overall <- round(100 * dat1$values/sum(dat1$n), 2)
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Hypertension = c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1),
  Diabetes =  c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1),
  `Other NCD` = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1),
  check.names = FALSE
)
```